# SQL select dates from multi rows and datediff total hours

Tags: sql, date, compare

Hi have records entered into a table, I want to get the hours worked between rows.

> ```
> id    memberid    dayname datesigned          orderinout
> 310   987654321   Friday  2021-08-13 09:22:42    1
> 311   987654321   Friday  2021-08-13 10:15:50    2
> 312   987654321   Friday  2021-08-13 10:20:00    3
> 313   987654321   Friday  2021-08-13 12:36:15    4
> 314   987654321   Friday  2021-08-13 13:01:55    5
> 315   987654321   Friday  2021-08-13 18:55:41    6
> ```

Ideally I would like to work select a member and get the date signed, easy. then do a datediff to work out the hh:mm:ss difference. all good with 2 dates but multi on the same day? little stuck.

> ```
> SELECT TIMEDIFF(MAX(datesigned),MIN(datesigned)) AS HoursIn
> WHERE memberid = '987654321' 
> AND dayname = 'Friday'
> ```

when the date is saved, it will assign a number, first record will be 1 and so on for the member and the date.
so need to get the results for 1+2 then 3+4, 5+6 so on. might even be an odd one.

Any suggestions as im totally lost.

Comment: I don't know if your data structure can be changed, but it would be easier to get the data you want if, instead of having separate rows, each in/out pair were in one row with one column for in time and one column for out time. So a clock in event starts a new row with clockintime = [now] and clockouttime = null. Then when a clock out happens, it fills in the clockouttime for the newest row.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the results you want.  The logic isn't obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LAG` function to achieve the next record. Arrange the columns using **orderinout** and access the next row with the `LAG` function. 1 and 2 , 3 and 4 and .............

The TIMEDIFF function exists in mysql, and assuming your database management system is mysql, the following code.

**in mysql**

```
SELECT 
       id,
       memberid,
       dayname,
       datesigned,
       orderinout,
       TIMEDIFF(datesigned,lag(datesigned,1) over(partition by memberid order by orderinout)) as HoursIn
from t
WHERE memberid = '987654321' 
AND dayname = 'Friday'
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b13812a7467c99f265a6c53ab217c159)

**in sql-server**

```
SELECT 
       id,
       memberid,
       dayname,
       datesigned,
       orderinout,
       CONVERT (TIME, datesigned - lag(datesigned,1) over(partition by memberid order by orderinout)) as HoursIn
from t
WHERE memberid = '987654321' 
AND dayname = 'Friday'
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bf11441b2c7ba0eb5ded4cc4e505d643)

If you want to calculate for all members and every day, use the `LAG` function as follows.

`lag(datesigned,1) over(partition by memberid,dayname order by orderinout)`

full query

```
SELECT 
       id,
       memberid,
       dayname,
       datesigned,
       orderinout,
       TIMEDIFF(datesigned,lag(datesigned,1) over(partition by memberid,dayname order by orderinout)) as HoursIn
from t
```